# Specific aggregation of values in rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

It seems a very easy task, but I am looking for a smart solution to calculate the column *aggr* based on the values of the four other columns (a, b, c, d) within the same row of a data frame.

See example below:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1),
                 b=c(1,2,1,3,2), 
                 d=c(1,2,3,3,3), 
                 e=c(2,2,3,3,2), 
                 aggr=c(1,2,1,3,2))
```

The special conditions are:

- if more than two out of four values within the same row have a value of 3, then the *aggr* value is 3;
- if more than two out of four values within the same row have a value of 2 or 3, then the *aggr* value is 2;
- if the previous conditions are not fulfilled, then the *aggr* value is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1,1),
             b=c(1,2,1,3,2), 
             d=c(1,2,3,3,3), 
             e=c(2,2,3,3,2))

df$aggr <- 1 + (rowSums(df == 3 | df == 2) > 2) + (rowSums(df == 3) > 2)
df
  a b d e aggr
1 1 1 1 2    1
2 1 2 2 2    2
3 1 1 3 3    1
4 1 3 3 3    3
5 1 2 3 2    2
```

Comment: Very clever, David.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Done!  Though I feel guilty taking credit.  I had never thought about how `apply(df, 1 ` solutions...) is unnecessary

Comment: The idea was yours, I just modified it a bit. My initial idea was to do it in 3 steps, so this is much better (+1).